# Spark SQL on Nested JSON array

Tags: json, apache-spark, multidimensional-array, apache-spark-sql

I have the below two JSON messages

```
[{
  "identifier": {
    "domain": "OFFICE ADDRESS",
    "id": "987654321",
    "version": 1
  },
  "payload": {
    
    "contactMethods": [
      {
        "faxDiallingNumber": "0000/11111",
        "objId": 8,
        "type": "Fax",
        "use": "Business Address"
      },
      {
        "objId": 9,
        "telephoneDiallingNumber": "0999/99999",
        "telephoneType": "Fixed",
        "type": "Telephone",
        "use": "Business Address"
      },
      {
        "addressLine1": "house no",
        "addressLine3": "street name",
        "addressLine4": "area name",
        "cityCode": "city name",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "objId": 10,
        "postalCode": "12345",
        "preferredContactMethodFlag": true,
        "type": "International Address",
        "use": "Registered"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "identifier": {
    "domain": "HOME ADDRESS",
    "id": "123456789",
    "version": 1
  },
  "payload": {
    
    "contactMethods": [
      {
        "faxDiallingNumber": "0000/22222",
        "objId": 11,
        "type": "Fax",
        "use": "home Address"
      },
      {
        "addressLine1": "house no",
        "addressLine3": "street name",
        "addressLine4": "area name",
        "cityCode": null,
        "countryCode": "US",
        "objId": 12,
        "postalCode": "45678",
        "preferredContactMethodFlag": true,
        "type": "International Address",
        "use": "Registered"
      },
      {
        "objId": 13,
        "telephoneDiallingNumber": "0999/88888,
        "telephoneType": "Fixed",
        "type": "Telephone",
        "use": "home Address"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

Using pyspark Spark SQL, I am trying something like below to find out the id where type is "International Address" and cityCode is null.

My output should be

[image]

Could you please let me know the correct and working syntax.

I tried explode, array_contains, flatten functions but haven't got it right.

```
select 
identified.id ,
payload.contactMethods.type,
payload.contactMethods.cityCode
from sample_json_df -- (will create a dataframe on the json file using pyspark)
where
payload.contactMethods.type = 'International Address'
and payload.contactMethods.cityCode is null
```

Answer (score 0):

explode should work like that:

```
SELECT
  id,
  contactMethods.type as type,
  contactMethods.cityCode
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      identifier.id,
      explode(payload.contactMethods) as contactMethods
    FROM
      sample_json_df
  )
WHERE
  contactMethods.type = 'International Address'
  AND contactMethods.cityCode is null
```